# Identify keys and value pairs of a PDF Document using iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I need to read a pdf document and populate values into a database table, it's fields are in the following format :

```
> Service Request              ID 00562464 APAG Notes                  
> 8/18/17 Contingent           Approval by 10/2/17
```

Where Service Request & APA Notes are the keys and ID 00562464 & 8/18/17 Contingent Approval by 10/2/17 are the values. When I read this PDF through iText PdfTextExtractor method I get the values as follows:

```
Service Request ID 00562464
APAG Notes 8/18/17 Contingent Approval by 10/2/17
```

Hence i cannot identify the keys and values seperately to populate the columns of the table. I am using the iText Java library.

Below is the code I have used to get the above output.

```
 PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);
 String textFromPage = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 1);
 System.out.println(textFromPage);
```

[image]

Comment: You need to post come code as well in order to get a good answer. What have you tried so far?

Comment: As well as the PDF you extract from.

Comment: @ErikFinnman Thanks, I have edited the question.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Thanks, I have attached an image of the PDF page.

Comment: What you call keys and what you call values is both merely text content of the pdf. Thus, you have to determine whether it is key or value by some criteria one can check. In the case at hand obvious choices would be the font used or the position. When using a `PdfTextExtractor`, you can select the strategy to use during extraction, and you can easily expand the default strategies to make use of such criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to separate the keys and of the PDF using the LocationTextExtractionStrategy provided with iText, below is the code

```
    SrPdfModel srpdfModel = new SrPdfModel();               
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);             
    Integer pages = reader.getNumberOfPages();          
    for(int i=1; i <= pages; i++){
       Rectangle mediaboxKeys=reader.getPageSize(i);
       mediaboxKeys.setRight((float) 100.00);
       RenderFilter[] filterKeys = {new RegionTextRenderFilter(mediaboxKeys)};
       FilteredTextRenderListener strategyKeys = new FilteredTextRenderListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), filterKeys);
       String[] keysFromPage = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i, strategyKeys).split("\\r?\\n");
}
```

I set the boundary of the keys region which is on the left side of the page by using the Rectangle objects set right property. I can similarly read the values of these keys by setting the left boundary.

Following link is helpful : https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-read-text-specific-position